# Verb for removing from end or beginning

Tags: suffixes, prefixes

We use "append" and "prepend" for adding to the end and to the beginning respectivly. Is there a word for removing in same place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following an  *append* or *prepend* operation, an *undo* or *reverse* would express removing an item from the same place.

More generally, verbs like the following are used to express removing something from the end of something: *truncate, chop, chomp*.  Removing from the beginning might be expressed by *pop, lop*, or *behead*.

In more detail:
• *[lop](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lop#Verb)*, “(transitive, usually with off) To cut off as the top or extreme part of anything, especially to prune a small limb off a shrub or tree, or sometimes to behead someone.”  A related word is *[defalcate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/defalcate#Verb)*,  “To cut off; to take away or deduct a part of”.
 • *[pop](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/)* , “Removes the element on top of the stack”; but note that Python's *pop* “removes and returns the last item in the list” which might be thought of as cutting off a head instead of a tail.
• *[chop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html)*, “Chops off the last character of a string and returns the character chopped”.  (More generally, *[chop](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chop#Verb)*, meaning “To sever with an axe or similar implement”, can also refer to chopping off heads vs. tails.)
• *[chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)*, “This safer version of chop removes any trailing string that corresponds to the current value of $/...”
• *[behead](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/behead#Verb)*, “To remove the head”.  Also see *[decapitate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decapitate#Verb)* and *[decollate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decollate#Verb)*, which besides its usual meaning of  “To separate the copies of multipart computer printout” has an older meaning,  “To behead”.
• *[truncate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/truncate#Verb)* means “To shorten something as if by cutting off part of it”.  Its etymology, «From Latin *truncātus*, perfect passive participle of *truncō* (“maim, reduce to a trunk”», is suggestive of cutting off head and limbs.  In many contexts today its use is more limited: for example, to [truncate](http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate) a file, a number, or a string means to chop off all of it after a certain distance from the beginning of it. *Decaudate* (mentioned in tchrist's comment),  to de-tail or to remove the tail of, is consonant with this sense of *truncate*.
• *[splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html)* and *[slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)* apply more generally than to either end of something, and can refer to extracting, deleting, replacing middle portions of things as well
• verb *[apocopate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apocopate#Verb)*, “To shorten using [apocope](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apocope#Noun); to remove the final sound or syllable”
• As mentioned in Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment, the verb form *procopate* that would correspond to noun *procope* (loss of beginning sound or syllable) isn't in use, but while of course noun *[apheresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apheresis_%28linguistics%29)*, “the loss of one or more sounds from the beginning of a word, especially the loss of an unstressed vowel” is well known, a verb form isn't.

Comment: You missed  `splice`.  As for how with *to behead* one can use the longer Latinate *decapitate* or *decollate*, for *untailed* (ppl. adj.) or for *to de-tail* (vb.)  — not to be confused with *detail* vb. :) — one can also use the someone lovelily Latinate albeit someone recondite ***decaudate*** /dɪˈkɔːdeɪt/, as in this OED citation:  “1864 *N. & Q. V.* 165 — The P. was originally an R. which has had the misfortune to be **dacaudated.”** Not to be confused with *ecaudate* (adj.), which never had one in the first place. 

Comment: If we are talking specifically about language and sounds, you can **apocopate** a word (removing letters or sounds at the end of the word), though I admit I’ve never seen anyone use **procopate** the would-be verbal equivalent of the antonymic _procope_. _Aphaeresis_ is the same as procope (and more common), but I can’t even begin to conjure up a verbal for that that would make any sense. _Aphaere_, perhaps? Or _aphaereticise_? Neither sounds very … possible.

Comment: @tchrist, thanks, *decaudate* is good.  I'd thought of writing "In more de-tail" but perished the thought. I've mentioned *splice* in edit

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, thanks, have added *apocopate* et al to answer

Answer (score 1):

If by removing in same place, you mean taking one word out and putting another in its stead, then that would simply be replace, as in search and replace.

On reflection, the title seems clearer than the question itself, so the verb would be [truncate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/truncate?q=truncate)

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of *curtail* or *truncate* for the loss or removal of a trailing portion. To my ear the distinction is that truncation is performed on a static object, and curtailment is done on a dynamic object. So a usage might be: "Her acceptance speech was curtailed by the orchestra's sudden increased volume, and further truncated in the transcript."

I know of only one very particular circumstance where a phrase exists specifically for the removal of the beginning of something: In the programming language **Lisp** there is a pair of operators (*car* and *cdr*) that respectively refer to the selection for the first item in a list, and the remainder of the list. A programming audience would for the most part understand these references.

In more general circumstances, the use of *beheading* would often be understood for the loss of the head, or beginning, of something. In other contexts it might be only nonsense.

Or, one could simply refer to the *remainder* as that left over after removal of the leading portion.